# Javascript Promise Single Function Callback

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have two ways to run a series of initialisations (that need to happen in a particular order).

**Method 1:**

```
dispatch('initialize1')
  .then(dispatch('initialize2'))
  .then(dispatch('initialize3'))
  .then(dispatch('initialize4'))
  .catch((error) => Log(error.message))
```

**Method 2:**

```
dispatch('initialize1')
  .then(() => dispatch('initialize2'))
  .then(() => dispatch('initialize3'))
  .then(() => dispatch('initialize4'))
  .catch((error) => Log(error.message))
```

Method 2 works perfectly, but Method 1 seems to not wait for each to finish before it moves onto the next one.

But this really confuses me because I thought that if I chained promises with thens (no callback function), it would wait for each to complete (synchronously); but if I put each promise in a callback then as soon as it received the promise it'd move onto the next - but it's the opposite??
Can anyone explain this to me?

*I don't think it's relevant, but the dispatch comes from Vue's Vuex Store.*

Comment: the difference is, Method 2 is passing a function to .then (correct as that what .then expects); Method 1 is passing the **result of calling a function** to .then (which .then will ignore, unless the result of calling dispatch returns a function - and anyway, dispatch is called immediately)

Comment: JavaScript evaluates arguments **before** they are passed to the callee. That means whenever you have `foo(bar())`, `bar` is **always** executed **first** and its *return value* is passed to `foo`. It makes absolutely no difference what these functions are doing. Here is a simplified example: `[1,2,3].forEach(() => console.log('here'))` vs `[1,2,3].forEach(console.log('here'))`.

Comment: The argument to `then` needs to be a function. `() => dispatch('initialize2')` is a function. `dispatch('initialize2')` is a function call that might not result in a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In method 1, you passed the result of calling the function `dispatch` **instead of passing a function** to the Promise chain, this will cause the `dispatch` functions be called first before the Promise chain actually starts executing, i.e. the `dispatch` functions has already been called when you initialize the chain.

You can check it out directly by running the following code right at your browser's console:

```
const dispatch = something => something

typeof dispatch('apple') === 'string' // true

typeof (() => { dispatch('apple') }) === 'function' // true
```

In method 2, you are passing functions this time, so the functions will be called **at the right time** by Promise, **instead of being run at start**.

Answer (score 0):

Because you need a wrapper function in the first case:

```
.then(function() {
  dispatch('initialize2')
})
```

Here you do the same thing:

```
.then(() => dispatch('initialize2'))
```

`() => ...` is a wrapper function similat to `function() {...}`.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at how promises are supposed to work. In short they are made of two pieces, a `resolve`algorithm and a `then` method available on promise instances. Your first example cannot work because it does not follow the semantics ( signature ) of the `then` method.

They are as follow : let `p` a promise, `f` a JS value. Calling `p.then(f)` we have the following case :

- if `f` is not a `function` it is ignored, and `p.then(f)` returns a new promise `q` eventually settled with the same state as `p`.
- if `f` is a `function` then when `p` is settled with a value, calling `p.then(f)` will return a new promise `q` which will be settled with the value / error produced by f. This is the critical part and what makes promises interesting : the procedure you pass in to the `then` attr will only be called **after** a value / error has first been produced by the original promise, hence your issue with example 1.

There is ofc a little bit more than that to promises and their semantics : `then`takes two arguments, one for each path : value / error. The namings may differ but usually you see code along the lines :

```
p.then(proceed, handle)
```

with

```
function proceed ( successfulValueFromSomewhere ) { // return new value or promise }


function handle ( anErrorFromSomewhere ) { // handle it by returning a value or a promise ( for retry cases ) }
```

I mentioned earlier a `resolve` algorithm, this part is critical to understand how values returned from such handlers are used from the point of view of promises to create new promise.

This procedure ensures that your second example work, it works more or less like that ( please take a look at the specs or the docs at MDN for an in depth review ). Its purpose is to *transition* a promise to one of two states : `fulfilled` with a value or `rejected` with an error.

Let `v` be a value, `p` an `unsettled` promise to be resolved with `v`.

- if `v` has a `then` method then call it with the function `function ( v2 ) { resolve(v2); }` : which means that if the callback is called, rerun the procedure with the value provided (`v2`).
- if `v` does not have a `then` method then `fulfill` with `v`
- if at any point an error is thrown during the resolution then `reject`with the error.

This procedure is not really difficult and explains why promises compose nicely together : they will call each other's `then`method upon resolution, which means that they will execute sequentially if each callback returns a promise.

There is a bit more than that to the specs of promises, I strongly advise anyone to take a look at the articles on MDN and [this article](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/) about the motivations behind this new primitive added to the language and how it solves (some) problems.

If this answer is obscure please comment I'll try to be clearer :)

Comment: A bit obscure.
So if I use a callback .then(()=>f()) it will continue only once f() completes (which is what a callback is for).
Without one .then(f()) if f() returns a promise, as soon as the promise is received it'll continue (which is what promises are for).
So if f() didn't return a promise, but was just a regular function, would .then() wait for it to finish before moving on?
My understanding is that it would because it hasn't gotten a result yet?

Comment: Actually I just tested this and it appears (unless my test is flawed) that if the inner function is not returning a promise, then you do not need to use a callback (and my method 1 would be fine) - because as @felix-king pointed out: parameter functions are evaluated first.